# amCharts convert unixtime to readable date

Tags: angularjs, parsing, amcharts

I want to show stacked area chart using amCharts, anything else worked as well but date on it was parsed incorrectly.

```
"dataProvider": [{
    "date": 1482192000,
    "cars": 1587,
    "motorcycles": 650,
    "bicycles": 121
}
```

Property named as *date* on above data package cannot be converted to readable date like "DD/MM/YYYY"

Finally, the chart  must show 30 days of chosen month.
Here is my **CodePen**:
 [CodePen Stacked Area Chart](https://codepen.io/trungnguyenviet/pen/jBbdbG/)

Comment: It looks like amCharts expects an actual Javascript `Date` object.  Try changing the unix timestamps to dates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Comment: @stderr - Unix timestamps are supported, but they need to be in milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data and setup are both incorrect. Here's a list of what's wrong and how to fix them

1) [`dataDateFormat`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#dataDateFormat) is used for *parsing* string dates, not formatting them. Since you're using unix timestamps, you don't need this property at all, so you can remove it.

2) Your unix timestamps must also be in milliseconds in order for this to work. Seconds will give you invalid times.

3) Your data must be sorted in ascending date order for it to render correctly. Your data is currently in mixed order.

As for your other questions:

To format your dates, you have to set the [`dateFormats` array](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#dateFormats) in your categoryAxis to the desired format strings as [described here](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/formatting-dates/). For DD/MM/YYYY:

```
"categoryAxis": {
  // other properties omitted:
  "dateFormats": [{period:'fff',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},
    {period:'ss',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},
    {period:'mm',format:'JJ:NN'},
    {period:'hh',format:'JJ:NN'},
    {period:'DD',format:'DD/MM/YYYY'}, //you may need to change the entries for 'WW' and 'MM' as well, depending on the amount of visible data
    {period:'WW',format:'MMM DD'},
    {period:'MM',format:'MMM'},
    {period:'YYYY',format:'YYYY'}]
  // ...
}
```

To automatically zoom on chart load, you can add a [`rendered`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#rendered) event similar to how the demos on the AmCharts website does it and call any of the zoom methods, for example:

```
"listeners": [{
  "event": "rendered",
  "method": function(e) {
    // different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates, zoomToCategoryValues
    e.chart.zoomToDates(new Date(2017, 1, 1), new Date(2017, 1, 15));
  }
}]
```

Here's an updated codepen with all of the aforementioned fixes [here](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/967d6586ee189d5b883642c689071783/?editors=0010).